# Cargo test does not work anymore because of Libsodium failing on: pwhash_argon2i and pwhash_argon2id

Tags: rust, libsodium, nearprotocol

I just updated my near-bindgen version and when trying to run tests using: 
`cargo test --package my-package`

I get the following error caused by Libsodium:

```
make[4]: *** [test-suite.log] Error 1
make[3]: *** [check-TESTS] Error 2
make[2]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

In the Libsodium testsuite summary you see that the following steps fail.

```
FAIL: pwhash_argon2i
FAIL: pwhash_argon2id
```

This happens on MacOS `Catalina V10.15`, `v10.15.1` and `rustup 1.20.2` and only when trying to run the `cargo test` command. Deploying and building works perfectly fine.

UPDATE: looks like common issue:

- https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/848
- https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/878

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug in Xcode 11: https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/881

But the stable version of libsodium has had a workaround since August (right after the first Xcode beta with the bug was released).